# I am having access denied to generate a new bootkey

Tags: bootnodes

When I try to run the command to bootnode -genkey bootnode.key

it would say:

> Fatal: open bootnode.key: Access is denied.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: windows 10 home @RomanFrolov